# error: "Typerror: 'bool' objects is not callable" in mu 1.0.3 (pygame)

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm new to python and I am trying to make a game in python. I reviewed some other posts of this error but I didn't understand them. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
if player_x == 1024 - scene_x_offset:
        player_x = 0
        current_scene += 1
        update_scene()
        player_x = scene_x_offset

def update_scene():
    scene_width = SCENE_DATA[current_scene][0]
    scene_height = SCENE_DATA[current_scene][1]
    scene_map = SCENERY_MAPS[current_scene]
    scene_x_offset = (8 - scene_width) / 2 * 128
    scene_y_offset =  (8 - scene_height) / 2 * 128
```

and I get the error message:
File "my_python_thingy.py", line 295, in game_loop
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.

I've left out unnecessary code that doesn't have anything to do with the error I'm getting.

Help would be appreciated, especially if it was in a format noobs like me can understand!

Thanks

Comment: do you have another variable called `update_scene`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear from the code you gave us, but the error is most likely caused by the fact that there is a boolean (True or False) variable somewhere that has the same name as the function your trying to call when the error is raised. If you have a boolean named `update_scene` you should rename either it or the function `update_scene()`.